# How to find number of TLB misses in a code snippet?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, paging, tlb

How can I calculate number of TLB misses in a code like the following code snippet assuming the page size is 1KB:

```
int i;
int p[1024];
for (i=0; i<1024; i++)
    p[i]=0;
```

I am interested in knowing the general rules to be able to calculate number of TLB misses in almost every given code snippet beside knowing the #TLB misses for this one.

Answer (score 3):

There cannot be any straight forward answer. The answer will drastically differ from one processor to another. First of all, the size of the TLB (number of entries) is not the same. Second, processors tend to use algorithms to retain more valuable entries (as they beieve them to be) and discard others. These algorithms are never published.

Besides that, some part of TLB will be used for reading instructions, something will be used by the OS. This means that you cannot know the exact result.

Wikipedia provides the following info:

- Size: 12 - 4,096 entries;
- Hit time: 0.5 - 1 clock cycle;
- Miss penalty: 10 - 100 clock cycles;
- Miss rate: 0.01 - 1%.

In your example an array of 1024 4-byte integers you will require 5 pages because most likely your array will not be a page boundary aligned. Each page will get its place in TLB once it will be accessed in a loop. Can this initial placement be treated as a TLB miss? To my knowledge there is no definite answer. Some people may answer yes, some people will answer no. I would answer no.

When the size of the TLB is not enough to store all pages, required by algorithm, then this be indisputably called a TLB miss. In your case if a TLB would have has just 2 entries, then there will be 3 misses.

Comment: Imagine that sizeof(int) is 4Byte. Can you solve it with this assumption?